# Python multi-processing one worker dynimc number of recievers of all worker data (1:n)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am planing to setup a small proxy service for a remote sensor, that only accepts one connection. I have a temporary solution and I am now designing a more robust version, and therefore dived deeper into the python multiprocessing module.

I have written a couple of systems in python using a main process, which spawns subprocesses using the `multiprocessing` module and used `multiprocessing.Queue` to communicate between them. This works quite well and some of theses programs/scripts are doing their job in a production environment.

The new case is slightly different since it uses 2+n processes:

- One *data-collector*, that reads data from the sensor (at 100Hz) and every once in a while receives short ASCII strings as command
- One *main-server*, that binds to a socket and listens, for new connections and spawns...
- n *child-servers*, that handle clients who want to have the sensor data

while communication from the child servers to the data collector seems pretty straight forward using a `multiprocessing.Queue` which manages a n:1 connection well enough, I have problems with the other way. I can't use a queue for that as well, because all child-servers need to get all the data the sensor produces, while they are active. At least I haven't found a way to configure a Queue to mimic that behaviour, as get takes the top most out of the Queue by design.

I looked into shared memory already, which massively increases the management overhead, since as far as I understand it while using it, I would basically need to implement a streaming buffer myself.

The only safe way I see right now, is using a redis server and messages queues, but I am a bit hesitant, since that would need more infrastructure than I like.

Is there a pure python internal way?

Answer (score 0):

maybe You can use MQTT for that ?

You did not clearly specify, but sounds like `observer pattern` -
or do You want the clients to poll each time they need data ?

It depends which delays / data rate / jitter etc. You can accept.

after You provided the information :

```
The whole setup runs on one machine in one process space. What I would like to have, is a way without going through a third party process
```

I would suggest to check for `observer pattern`.

More informations can be found for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpmfnqjgzQ&t=1882s

and

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/python/example

and

https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/tutorial-the-observer-pattern-in-python-879

and

https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Observer.html

Your Server should fork for each new connection and register with the observer, and will be therefore informed about every change.

Comment: As far as I understand it, MQTT would go down the same line as redis or sharememd. What I need is a way to transfer all data from one process (the sensor client) to a variable number of other processes (the sensor data servers), that are created whenever somebody wants to connect to the server. All servers need to get all the data from the sensor client. The whole setup runs on one machine in one process space. What I would like to have, is a way without going through a third party process (like redis, MQTT etc.).

Comment: @Jan , then its just a typical observer pattern. for an example You can look at https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/python/example